# How can I import a video to my HTML file? I only know how to add a GIF and IMG

Tags: html, image, video, import

Right.

All I need to is to import a video to my HTML file.

But how?

This is how to import a gif or a img:

```
<img src="a_file"></img>
```

How to add a video?

Do we use the `<img>` tag as well?

**EDITS HERE:**

Notes:

Does the `<video>` tag exist?



Changes:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an tag named `<video>` that you can use. Use the `src` attribute to add the video.

```
<video src=“path/to/video” ></video>
```

Note: even if you are beginner and have no clue about basic tags, I highly recommend that you give a search to figure out these and find them yourself. That would hep you in the long run.

Answer (score 1):

Html uses video tag. Try this:

```html
<video width="320" height="240" controls>
  <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="movie.ogg" type="video/ogg">
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

also checkout more on https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_video.asp

Comment: @Dangerousgame I would suggest you to use this structure by Aman rather than mine for better browser compatibility. Make sure you make changes according to your requirements.